# Android web app gets restart

Tags: android

I am facing problem in building android webview . The problem is that when the app is running and phone change direction , i mean from horizontal to vertical or vice versa the app get restarted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior is to restart the activity when the screen orientation changes.  You can write custom code to handle orientation change events yourself though:

- Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`
- Override `onConfigurationChanged` from your activity

Comment: Thanks to all.Its get solved but now what i am facing is that when it change direction i get a white blank page, alhtough i have enabled javascript and other settings . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default android behaviour is to destroy and recreate the activity on orientation change. You can either override `onSaveInstanceState()` to save your application data before destroy, or you can call `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to keep hold of a stateful object. See [the android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Umar,

You will want to add the `android:configChanges="orientation"` parameter to your `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to prevent your activity from restarting on orientation change.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (usually a decent fit for lighter Activities that don't have state outside a WebView, for instance) is to absorb the rotation event and let the view redraw itself. See http://www.androidguys.com/2008/11/11/rotational-forces-part-three/ - the idea is:

> 1. Put an android:configChanges entry in
>      your file, listing the configuration
>      changes you want to handle yourself
>      versus allowing Android to handle for
>      you.
> 2. Implement onConfigurationChanged()
>      in your Activity, which will be called
>      when one of the configuration changes
>      you listed in android:configChanges
>      occurs

Comment: Thanks to all.Its get solved but now what i am facing is that when it change direction i get a white blank page, alhtough i have enabled javascript and other settings . Thanks

Comment: It might help if you post your source in your question above, then.

Answer (score 1):

See also: [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Answer (score 0):

umar... Saving instance state is quite different on the Android. On a soft kill (phone rotation) you may save your non view state in onSaveInstanceState using bundles. On a hard kill (back button while activity has focus) you may elect to save your non view and view state in onStop perhaps using preferences. You can restore your state in onCreate.

You can leverage the fact that IF onSaveInstanceState is called it will be called BEFORE onStop. So this lets you set a flag isSavedInstanceState to true in onSaveInstanceState to avoid saving prefs in onStop except on a hard kill. The trick is to reset the flag isSavedInstanceState to false in onResume NOT in onCreate.

JAL

I have sample code [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/saving-instance-state).